# In-class init (assignment style) vs constructor performance

Tags: c++

To get in-class init to select the constructor I want, it seems to be necessary to use the assignment style of in-class init.

```
class Foo {
  // This lets me sets the vector size
  std::vector<char>  buf = std::vector<char>(BUF_SIZE);

  // this didn't compile and made me realize finding another way to provide constructor parameters was necessary
  // std::vector<char>  buf{BUF_SIZE};
};
```

Does this mean that to initialize "buf" in this style, two objects are constructed, an assignment operator is called and the second object is destroyed? Or is this just syntactic sugar and the code generated ends up being the same as:

```
class Bar {
public:
  Bar() : buf(BUF_SIZE) {}

  std::vector<char>  buf;
};
```

Possibly this is compiler specific?

Comment: `std::vector<char>  buf{BUF_SIZE}` and `std::vector<char>  buf(BUF_SIZE)` do different things - so which one do you want?

Comment: Any good compiler would elide that, but in C++17, there's nothing to elide anyway.

Comment: I clarified my post to indicate that my goal was to set the initialize size of the vector, rather than provide any sort of initial values.

Comment: There are indeed 2 objects constructed, but I expect elision with correct optimization flag.

Comment: @chris can you clarify why there is nothing to elide?

Comment: @UnholySheep Now run the test again with `BUF_SIZE` having type `size_t`. :)

Comment: @cdhowie still gives different result: http://ideone.com/Gca6kM

Comment: @UnholySheep Odd, isn't size_t -> char a narrowing conversion?

Comment: @cdhowie, Either the compiler knows the value fits and therefore it isn't narrowing or the narrowing causes an error instead of choosing the other constructor.

Comment: @cdhowie When specifying that `BUF_SIZE` is `const` it will correctly emit a warning/error that it is narrowing, if it is non-const (as in the one I linked) it will call the initializer list constructor (which will then construct the `vector` with an invalid value and lead to UB when trying to access it)

Comment: @Kevin, It's more commonly known as guaranteed elision, but that's a bit of a misnomer and can cause confusion around where it applies. There's more info here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: @UnholySheep Aha, the source of my confusion comes from the fact that explicit constructors are not considered if an `std::initializer_list` overload does not produce a match. The `vector(size_type)` constructor is `explicit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good compiler will elide the copy and construct a single vector.

---

With this optimization disabled, what happens depends on whether you are compiling with C++11 support.  I am looking at this line in particular, absent the context of being a class member (as non-static member initializers are a C++11 feature):

```
std::vector<char>  buf = std::vector<char>(BUF_SIZE);
```

- Prior to C++11, one vector would be constructed (the temporary) then `buf` would be copy-constructed from this temporary, then the temporary is destructed.  If the vector is large, this can indeed be very inefficient.
- Starting with C++11, the temporary is constructed and then `buf` would be *move-constructed* from it; `buf` will "steal" the data pointer from the temporary and leave the temporary in an unspecified (but valid) state, then the temporary is destructed.  The overhead for this process is trivial and constant.

Comment: Before C++11, that syntax were not valid. ;-)

Comment: Ok thanks! To summarize then: C++11 allows you to now also init non-static data members with an assignment style in-class and this has similarities to initializing static data members which has always been possible to do. C++11 also added move-construction that makes both cases more efficient. According to @Chris above, C++17 added "guaranteed" elision to improve it even further:  en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision